# Decode Url Recursively giving error for valid URL

Tags: javascript, urldecode

I have trying to decode Recursively encoded url . But for even valid URL it is giving error .

I am calling

`decodeURIRecursively({},"https%3A%2F%2Fgmail.com%3Frate%3D95%25")`

It should return "https://gmail.com?rate=95%" But return string.

If I modify code and change catch block to return url it works well for this scenario but for malformed URL like `decodeURIRecursively({},'%E0%A4%A')`.  It gives same url .

```js
    const decodeURIRecursively = (req, url) => {
        // Early return on missing required parameter
        if (!req || !url) {
          return '';
        }
        
        try {
          while (decodeURIComponent(url) !== url) {
            
            url = decodeURIComponent(url);         
           
          }
        } catch (e) {
         
          return ''; // Return empty string as it is not a safe string to decode and use in
        }
      
        return url;
      };

console.log(decodeURIRecursively({},"https%3A%2F%2Fgmail.com%3Frate%3D95%25"));
```

Comment: _“It should return `https://gmail.com?rate=95%`”_ - why? That is not actually a valid URL.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're trying to achive

Answer (score 0):

The url "https://gmail.com?rate=95%" has one invalid character which is "%".
So that why you get exception when run final step decodeURLComponent.
%3A, %2F, %3F... can be  decode but only "%" is impossible.

```
catch (e) {
   return url; 
}
```

Return url when get the error is good choice as you mentioned.
My question is why you need decode recursively?
As I see you only need run decodeURLComponent one time.

Comment: It is generic function there can be any type of encoded url . Not only once